# How to mix series, data and xAxis category in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I need to create a column chart that is able to mix series, data and xAxis. Perhaps the example below may be easier to understand my problem:

I have a set of products that needs to be my xAxis category. Let's call them A, B, C and D.
For each product, I have 2 values to be shown as column, values A1 and A2 for A, B1 and B2 for B, and so on.
All the values on A1, B1, C1 and D1 must be called "hello" and the others A2, B2, C2 and D2 must be "world". "Hello" must be blue and "world" must be red.
Also, when I mouseover each column, all of them have different values, but must always shows the according product.

I need to create a JSON file structure that will be generated from a Java application.
The image below may help the example as well.
[image]
[Edit] As requested these are the two code I tested (JSON files):

This is definitely the wrong way:

```
{      
    "series": [
        {
            "type": "column",
            "name": "A"
            "composition": {
                "custom_tooltip": "My custom tooltip for A"
            },
            "data": [{
                "name": "A1",
                "color": "#777777",
                "y": 37.225
            }, {
                "name": "A2",
                "color": "#0088cc",
                "y": 31.013
            }]
        },
        {
            "type": "column",
            "name": "B"
            "composition": {
                "custom_tooltip": "My custom tooltip for B"
            },
            "data": [{
                "name": "B1",
                "color": "#777777",
                "y": 31.888
            }, {
                "name": "B2",
                "color": "#0088cc",
                "y": 28.910
            }]
        },
        {
            "type": "column",
            "name": "C"
            "composition": {
                "custom_tooltip": "My custom tooltip for C"
            },
            "data": [{
                "name": "C1",
                "color": "#777777",
                "y": 49.101
            }, {
                "name": "C2",
                "color": "#0088cc",
                "y": 41.001
            }]
        },
        {
            "type": "column",
            "name": "D"
            "composition": {
                "custom_tooltip": "My custom tooltip for D"
            },
            "data": [{
                "name": "D1",
                "color": "#777777",
                "y": 59.890
            }, {
                "name": "D2",
                "color": "#0088cc",
                "y": 55.491
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I also have tried basic configuration for both column and bar.

[Edit2] My problem was solved with examples provided by @jlbriggs. I updated my JSON file and will use the this.point.var functionality to display customised tooltips.

For each "data" with "series" I'll add variables to create the tooltips.

```
{      
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D"
        ]
    },

    "series": [
        {
            "name": "Hello",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#777777",
            "data": [
            {
                "tooltip": "Yo, I'm a cool tooltip for A1",
                "y": 37.225
            },
            {
                "tooltip": "Yo, I'm a cool tooltip for B1",
                "y": 42.542
            },
            {
                "tooltip": "Yo, I'm a cool tooltip for C1",
                "y": 49.093
            },
            {
                "tooltip": "Yo, I'm a cool tooltip for D1",
                "y": 58.391
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "World",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#0088cc",
            "data": [
            {
                "tooltip": "Yo, I'm a cool tooltip for A2",
                "y": 37.225
            },
            {
                "tooltip": "Yo, I'm a cool tooltip for B2",
                "y": 42.542
            },
            {
                "tooltip": "Yo, I'm a cool tooltip for C2",
                "y": 49.093
            },
            {
                "tooltip": "Yo, I'm a cool tooltip for D2",
                "y": 58.391
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The .js file will have:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return this.point.tooltip;
    }
},
```

Thanks,
Eugenio

Comment: In order for us to help you, what have you tried?

Comment: have you looked through examples (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic) ?

Comment: this is all pretty basic stuff - look at the demos and you should see everything you need to accomplish this.  do you have a specific question?

Comment: @dIsoVi probably it could be a solution, but I need to have custom tooltip for each bar. Is it possible?

Comment: @jlbriggs I tried some of the examples but none of them was able to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you need to look at categories: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories

1a) in your data, you associate a data point with the correct category by using the array index of the category.

So, if your categories are ['A','B','C','D'], you align your data for group A by using an 'X' value of 0.  B = 1, etc.

You can do this without specifying the x values, simply by putting your data in the same order as the cetegories they correspond to.

2) tooltips

You are almost on the right track, you just have too much going on.

Simply specify a parameter in your data point object, and call it in the tooltip formatter:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fbMQf/

```
formatter:function()
```

You can also do a check in your formatter function for which series it is, and return a tooltip based on the series instead of just the point:

http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/313/

ie

```
tooltip:{
        formatter:function() {
            if(this.series.name == 'A') {
                return 'this is a a tooltip for series A';
            }
            else {
                return 'this is how series B tooltips look'
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver! I got you examples and mixed them up along with some tweaks and got the exactly result I was expecting. I didn't know about the this.point.var on the tooltip formatter function, now I can customize the tooltip accordingly. I'll update my question with the final JSON file. Thanks!